How to collect all emits from StateFlow in test?
So I want to test my viewModel logic. We use MVI architecture, so we have UI state object. When a certain event happens, the viewModel handles it, and updates the state. In my case there should be 3 emits.
You can see an example of my problem:
ViewModel:

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableSharedFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.asStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.update
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class TestViewmodel: ViewModel() {
    private val _event = MutableSharedFlow<TestEvent>()

    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(TestState())
    val state = _state.asStateFlow()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _event.collect{
                handleEvent(it)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun handleEvent(event: TestEvent){
        if(event == TestEvent.GetData){
            getTestData()
        }
    }

    private fun getTestData(){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            _state.update {
                it.copy(
                        loading = true
                )
            }
           // delay(100)

            val data = getApiData()

            _state.update {
                it.copy(
                        loading = false
                )
            }
           // delay(100)

            handleApiData(data)
        }
    }

    private fun handleApiData(list: List<String>){
        _state.update {
            it.copy(
                    data = list
            )
        }
    }

    private suspend fun getApiData(): List<String>{
        delay(1000)
        return listOf("ffefe","ffefe","fdfdfd")
    }

    fun setEvent(event: TestEvent){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _event.emit(event)
        }
    }
}

data class TestState(
        val loading: Boolean = false,
        val data: List<String> = emptyList()
)

sealed interface TestEvent{
    data object GetData: TestEvent
}

TestClass:
import io.kotest.matchers.shouldBe
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.drop
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.first
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.resetMain
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.runTest
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.setMain
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith

@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class TestViewModelTest(){
    private lateinit var viewModel: TestViewmodel

    @BeforeAll
    fun setUp(){
        Dispatchers.setMain(Dispatchers.Unconfined)
        viewModel = TestViewmodel()
    }

    @AfterAll
    fun afterAll(){
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }

    @Test
    fun testEmit() = runTest {
        val state = viewModel.state
        viewModel.setEvent(TestEvent.GetData)

        val result = state.drop(2).first()

        result.data.size shouldBe 3
    }

    @Test
    fun testEmitWithTurbine() = runTest {
        val state = viewModel.state

        state.test {
            viewModel.setEvent(TestEvent.GetData)

            awaitItem()
            awaitItem()
            awaitItem().data.size shouldBe 3
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun testEmitByGoogle() = runTest {
        val state = viewModel.state
        val result = mutableListOf<TestState>()

        val collectionJob = launch {
            state.toList(result)
        }

        viewModel.setEvent(TestEvent.GetData)
        
        result[2].data.size shouldBe 3

        collectionJob.cancel()
    }
}

So my problem, when I try to test is, the test runs for about 1 minute, and after that it exits with UncompletedCoroutinesError.
I noticed that, if I put a delay after every state update, the test will success, but it isn't a good solution.
I tried some ideas from Google docs, but they didn't help. Although the test didn't exit with UncompletedCoroutinesError, but the test failed. It failed, because the state property stored just the first emit, at least it seemed.
I also tried to use Turbine library, but the result was the same.
When I debugged the code, I noticed that the assertion is called before the second/third emit happens, it explains why I have always just 1 item in the list, but I have no idea why is it happening.

The important parts are missing, so this isn't reproducible. Can you create a minimal reproducible example for us? And have you tried using advanceUntilIdle to wait for the coroutine?

Thanks @Leviathan, I try to create a small runnable class asap

Are you using repository?

No I don't, actually I use UseCases, but the code snippet what I attached just mocking the API call

Maybe I found a solution, I not gonna say it is the best, but at least, it does what I want.

class TestCollector<T>(
        scope: TestScope,
        numberOfEmit: Int,
        flow: StateFlow<T>,
        private val timeOut: Long,
        private val timeUnit: TimeUnit
) {
    private val values = mutableListOf<T>()
    private val countDownLatch = CountDownLatch(1)

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    private val job = scope.launch(UnconfinedTestDispatcher((scope.testScheduler))) {
        flow.collect {
            values.add(it)
            if (values.size == numberOfEmit) {
                countDownLatch.countDown()
                this.cancel()
            }
        }
    }

    fun getData(): List<T> {
        if (!countDownLatch.await(timeOut, timeUnit)) {
            job.cancel()
            throw TimeoutException("StateFlow value was never set.")
        }
        return values
    }
}

fun <T> StateFlow<T>.test(
        scope: TestScope,
        numberOfEmit: Int = 1,
        timeOut: Long = 10,
        timeUnit: TimeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS,
): TestCollector<T> {
    return TestCollector(
            scope = scope,
            numberOfEmit = numberOfEmit,
            timeOut = timeOut,
            timeUnit = timeUnit,
            flow = this
    )
}

Usage:
    @Test
    fun testEmit() = runTest {
        val state = viewModel.state

        val testCollector = state.test(this, numberOfEmit = 4)
        viewModel.setEvent(TestEvent.GetData)
        val result = testCollector.getData()

        result.size shouldBe 4
    }

In my case the result size was 4, because it collected the init value as well.
I was also able to resolve this by using Turbine library.
In this case we can use skipItems() function and after that, the awaitItem() returns with the fourth emit


StateFlow is an observable data holder, which can be collected to
observe the values it holds over time as a stream. Note that this
stream of values is conflated, which means that if values are set in a
StateFlow rapidly, collectors of that StateFlow are not guaranteed to
receive all intermediate values, only the most recent one.

You can use FakeRepository, When testing the ViewModel with this fake, you can emit values from the fake to trigger updates in the ViewModel's StateFlow, and then assert on the updated value.
Check this link.
Update
You should use your TestState class like this.
sealed class TestState {
    data class Success(val data: Any): TestState()
    data class Error(val error: String): TestState() //This is optional in your case.
    object Loading: TestState()
}


Thanks, but I don't agree with this solution.
If you check my example, the viewModel emits the data.  So I don't have, and I don't van to create extra logic for this.
Other than that, in my example there will be 3 emits, so the most recent one will contain the data, but instead of this, the test receives only the very first emission, which is the loading = true

Paste your TestState and TestEvent class

First box of code already contains it, I put it into the TestViewModel file
